# Android Studio - Missing map markers

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I'm currently working on my map app using android studio. Everything's working perfectly except for the marker that I've added. I've been using the official documentation [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) as my guide but can't find my marker anywhere when I try to load the map. Am I missing something?

Here's my map activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;

public class MapFragment extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
    private SupportMapFragment sMapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);

        sMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        sMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap)
    {
        LatLng one = new LatLng(10.178, 122.560);
        LatLng ILOILO = new LatLng(10.730278, 122.548889);

        mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ILOILO, 12));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Empty Lot 1")
            .snippet("blah blah blah")
            .position(one)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
    }
}
```

And here's my map_layout:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**EDIT**

I've also tried removing `private SupportMapFragment sMapFragment;` and changing my

```
        sMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        sMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

into

```
        SupportMapFragment sMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        sMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

but I can't still find my marker.

Comment: @Xingchen I tried but it's still the same.

Comment: How about your Layout file, is there 'class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"' in your 'Fragment'?

Comment: @Xingchen Yes, there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your Java code looks fine.. Try editing your XML files as per the Google Documentation for onMapReadyCallback listener

```
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Hope this would Help!!

Comment: Thank you!! Btw, it seems that there's a zoom limit unlike when I was working with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It's also a good idea to make sure that your device's location services are enabled. 
I wasted several hours looking for a solution and eventually discovered my location services were not enabled!